# Why is ethanol, water and amonium needed for DMG to react with nickel?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism

I had this question on a test and I'm unsure on why ethanol is required for the reaction.
I understand that you need the ammonia and water to make oxonium ions needed for the reaction to occur.
We had a hint about the solubility of ethanol in water (very high), ammonia (high) and DMG (low)
[image: reaction]

Comment: Have you considered the reverse, solubility DMG and eventually Ni(DMG)2 in ammonia, water and ethanol ?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I'm not that good in chemistry...

Comment: The DMG - Ni complex is likely reasonably soluble in EtOH/water but not in water. This insolubilty will prevent the reaction going to completion.